# How to install Ubuntu on computer with no operating system?

Tags: boot

We have a Toshiba Satellite A305-S6872, we took out the old hard drive, and put in a new one.  We downloaded the Ubuntu ISO, and put it on a DVD.  Now, when we try to boot from the DVD, nothing shows up.  What should we do.
Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: I suspect your problem is that you must burn the iso to DVD not just copy it as if it was a simple file.

Comment: 1st check your BIOS and confirm it is set to boot from DVD prior to your hard disc. Also check if the hdd is recognized inside your BIOS. Next confirm you create a bootable DVD and not copied the ISO as a file to the disc.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the live disk. Go into bios boot menu by pressing the key it says you have to press at the first screen you see. Now select the dvd drive; it may be called optical something or dvd drive. You should load Ubuntu. If that doesn't work, create another dvd. Make sure you burn the image. If you copy and paste, it won't work.